# Python ticTacToe game with turtle

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe, turtle-graphics

I am working on a TicTacToe game for a class assignment, there are places where I am stuck and could use some help...the game should be able to draw Xs and Os with in grids and execute a full game
here is my code

```
import turtle
import math 
import random 

cellSize = 100
turtleWidth =10
gridColor  = 'Black'
xColor = 'Blue'
oColor = 'Red'
winColor = 'green'
drawColor = 'Gray'

winninTriples = ((0,1,2)

def onclick(x, y):
    print x, y

turtle.Screen().onscreenclick(onclick)
  #the grid is here 
def drawGrid(pen, length, xcoor, ycoor):
      startX = [xcoor,xcoor,xcoor+length, xcoor+(2*length)]
      endX = [xcoor+(3*length), xcoor+(3*length), xcoor+(length),xcoor+(2*length)]
      startY = [ycoor+(2*length),ycoor+length, ycoor, ycoor]
      endY = [ycoor+(2*length), ycoor+length, ycoor+(3*length),ycoor+(3*length)]
      for grid in range(4):
          p.up()
          p.goto(startX[grid],startY[grid])
          p.down()
          p.goto(endX[grid],endY[grid])

     pen = turtle.Turtle()       
     pen.width(5)
     drawGrid(pen,100,-40,-50)

     board = [0,1,2,
              3,4,5,
              6,7,8]


    def theWinnner(grid0,grid1,grid2,grid3,grid4,grid5,grid6,grid7,grid8):
        X = 'X wins'
        O = 'O wins'
        No = 'Draw'
        #this was a code that was given, I am supposed to add on to it and I am not sure how it can be modified and what should I put as the parameters when executing it? 
   def drawX(t,x,y,size):
       drawLine(t, x + size/4, y + size/4, x - size/4, y - size/4)
       drawLine(t, x - size/4, y + size/4, x + size/4, y - size/4)
   def drawO(t,x,y,size):
       t.cirle(size)


   def Move():
       y = input("Please choose a row:")
       x = input("Now please choose a column:")
       if x in ['0','1','2']  and y in ['0','1','2']:
          return("Your destination is " + y + " " + "and " + x)
       else:
          return("One or more of your dimensions is out of bounds")
```

This is the work I have so far, I am kind of lost in regards to what to do next.

Comment: What does it do now? Anything? Which step are you confused about?

Comment: I'm starting to think that we need a new tag [tag:python-tic-tac-toe-turtle-assigment].

Comment: Please specify what your problems are and provide a test case. If you execute it - what are your errors etc. Some of your code doesn't follow conventions. Consider to take a code review at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This would be off-topic at code review SE, which only accepts working code.

Answer (score 0):

I took the code, made it work, and figured out what to do next. 
The first thing I would do is set up a board using `Turtle()` functions. I would hide the turtle using `Turtle.ht()`, then make lines, and figure out the region that each square is in. using if loops, make 'buttons' or spaces where, if pressed, will be an `X` or an `O`.
Then using `Turtle.forward()`, `Turtle.right()`, `Turtle.back()`, and `Turtle.left()` make `X`'s and `O`'s. Also, fix your indentations, that will throw several errors, and add `from turtle import *`.

Comment: You should include the implementation you've made